# Need to screen mirror/cast... not sure if EC2 is the right solution

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, vnc

I would like my multiple users around the world to type a specific address in their browser and be able to see the screen on my EC2 instance.

I would like to do this because I would like an EC2 instance to run a live dashboard.

Can someone please tell me what would be the best service to run in order to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You could probably run **teleconferencing-type software** that lets people connect to a computer and view the screen (eg Webex). It would be just like a webinar, but with no humans talking.

However, this is a very **inefficient** way to share the screen. The overhead protocol of having to send every pixel change to every client is probably overkill.

Instead, it would be easier to **regularly capture the screen of the EC2 instance and save it to S3**. Then each other computer could simply retrieve the picture from S3, updating every few minutes, and display it on their screen.

(Of course, the simpler solution is to publish the dashboard as HTML rather than sharing the screen of a machine, but I will assume you have a rather complex application that you cannot publish using web technologies.)